# How to configure Create-react-app less module with customize-cra(2.x)?

Tags: less, create-react-app, css-modules, react-app-rewired

I used create-react-app(typescripts) to build a project, and added antd@3.26.13 with customize-cra as [the website I was following](https://3x.ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) told me.

I would like use the module.css, and I want to use module.less, like css, but encountered some error messages:

```
./src/layout/basic.module.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-8-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-8-3!./src/layout/basic.module.less)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
```

My code follows:

```
const {
    override,
    addWebpackAlias,
    fixBabelImports,
    addLessLoader,
    addDecoratorsLegacy
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
    addWebpackAlias({
        "@":require('path').resolve(__dirname,"src")
    }),
    fixBabelImports('import',{
        libraryName:'antd',
        libraryDirectory:'es',
        style:true
    }),
    addLessLoader({
        javascriptEnabled:true,
        modifyVars:{'@primary-color':'#1DA57A'},
    }),
    addDecoratorsLegacy()
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of `customize-cra` isn't compatible with the latest version of `create-react-app`, to be precise with `css-loader`. Try to install `customize-cra@next` to get alpha version. They fixed that issue there.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is the GitHub PR that gives the context about the fix mentioned here: https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/pull/243